# NetLogo - nelson-winter entrepreneur model works but very slow - can it be sped up?

Tags: performance, netlogo

I've been working on a NetLogo model simulating entrepreneurs based on Nelson-Winter model. In the model, every tick there is a Demand and Supply for some product,then the price=Demand/Supply, so every tick the entrepreneurs have a chance to set up a company and make money, the probability of setting uo a companies is effected by the revenue of other companies set up by the entrepreneurs in the same group, entrepreneurs in the same group share the same gamma and lambda,gamma decide the proportion of profit invested in R&D(innovation and imitation),the lambda decided the proportion of R & D funding invested in the innovation. The success of RD will enhance the production.Finally it will returned the result of companies averaged by group, the companies in the same group will have the same companyNO and same gamma and lambda.
This process seems to work fine but it runs exceedingly slow, to the point that I'm worried I won't be able to feasibly run many simulations. Any ideas on how to speed up this process? In the earlier version model without group the model works really fast, so I think the problem lies in the grouping. The model code is getting pretty long, so I just added the part related to the grouping. I can provide more code to someone if the problem seems to lie elsewhere. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
globals[
  S;;aggregate supply
  SafterDie
  D;;aggregate demand
  P;;price of demand,P=D/S
  g b eta;;used for get demand
  file1
  file2
  totalGamma
  totalLambda
  NO
 ]
 breed [entrepreneurs a-entrepreneur]
 breed [companies a-company]

entrepreneurs-own[ 
 humanCapital 
 timesOfChuangYe
 chuangYe?;;chuang ye mei de
 gaiLv
 renGamma
 renLambda
 renNO
]

companies-own[
 humanCapital
 tempHumanCapital;;20140516
 oldHumanCapital
 initialCap
 initialTech
 companiesNO
 capitalK;;capital K,nedd money c*K
 gamma;;money uesd for R&D
 lambda;;money used for innovation in terms of imitation
 lifeLength
 RecentRevenue;;profit every tick
 production;;production of the tick    
 profit
 accumulatedInnovation
 accumulatedImitation 
]

to setup    
foreach n-values NoOfgroup [?]  [
      set bigGamma (random-in-range 0.4 1);;money uesd for innovation
      set bigLambda (random-in-range 0.1 1);;money used for innovation VS imitation
      set NO (? + 1)
      create-entrepreneurs numberOfentreprenursInEveryGroup [ entrepreneur-setup ]
      ]

to entrepreneur-setup ;; turtle procedure
 set color red
 set shape "line";;line
 move-to one-of patches
 set humanCapital random-in-range 0 1
 set chuangYe? 0;;if Entrepreneurship,0 no,1 yes
 set timesOfChuangYe 0;;Entrepreneurship times
 set renGamma bingGamma
 set renLambda bingLambda
 set renNO NO
end

to ifChuangYe
 ask entrepreneurs with [chuangYe? = 0]
 [
  let node1 self
  set gaiLv 0;;probability of entrepreneurship
  getProbabilitiOfEntrepreueur node1
  if (random-float 1 <= gaiLv)[
    set chuangYe? 1
    set timesOfChuangYe (timesOfChuangYe + 1)
    hatch-companies 1 [
     set color yellow
     set shape "house"
     create-link-with node1 [set color yellow]
     set humanCapital ([humanCapital] of node1);;!!!
     set companyNO ([renNO] of node1)
     set gamma ([renGamma] of node1);;money uesd for RD
     set lambda ([renLambda] of node1);;money used for innovation VS imitation
     set initialTech humanCapital
     set tempHumanCapital humanCapital
     set oldHumanCapital humanCapital
     company-setup
      ]
     ]
   ]  
  end

 to getProbabilitiOfEntrepreueur [node1]
   ask node1[
     let number renNO
      let co1 no-turtles
      let en1 entrepreneurs with [renNO = number];;get entrepreneur
      ask en1 [
        set co1 link-neighbors;;get company
         ]
      let total 0
      ask co1 [;;to link
        if lifeLength != 0 [
         let k lifeLength
         let singleRevenue 0
         if lifeLength >= 6 [set k 6]
         foreach n-values k [?]  [
         set singleRevenue (singleRevenue + (item ? RecentRevenue)/ (? + 1))
      ];;RecentRevenue is a list to collect a company's profit of every tick
    set total total + singleRevenue
    ]
   ]
set gaiLv (1 / 50 * total + 5 / 100)
;;show gaiLv
]
end

to imitation
  let newH 0
  ask companies[
   set accumulatedImitation (accumulatedImitation + (1 - lambda)* gamma * profit)
   if accumulatedImitation >= 0.3 * (capitalK ^ 3) [
   let co2 companies with [companyNO = companyNo]     
   set newH max ([humanCapital] of co2)
   if newH > humanCapital [set humanCapital newH set imNO imNO + 1]
   set accumulatedImitation (accumulatedImitation - 0.3 * (capitalK ^ 3))
   ]
  ]
```

end

Comment: I'd suggest splitting this up into more, smaller procedures and then using the profiler extension to tell you which procedures are the performance hotspots.

Comment: Note that `with` always searches the whole agentset, so every time you do e.g `companies with [companyNO = companyNo]` you're scanning every company. Usually in NetLogo it isn't necessary to use who numbers at all to look things up by who number; use links to connect turtles, or store a turtle reference directly in a variable. But without the profiling data, I have no idea whether that's the source of the slowness or not.